# How to get token with GooglePlus ? Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine

GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountName, scope);
How should I write this "scope".
Now I write "oauth2:"+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"+" "+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"

But the exception is "needPermission".

Who can help me?

Comment: It's obvious; *you need permission to use it*.

Answer (score 2):

In this [article](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) from the docs, you will find a nice quickstart guide on how to set up permissions, use the OAuth flows, and properly set up your scopes and permissions.

For further information, also take a look at [How to use OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

There are also many samples around the web that you will easily find just googling.

Comment: Thank you! But The date of the docs is 2013.I have read the document and found no problems